# os.system powershell with Quotation mark in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-os

```
import os

path = os.getcwd()
os.system('powershell.exe $env:path += "' + path + '\\ProgramFiles"')
```

This outputs as `$env:path += c:\programfiles`

And therefore returns as an error. Can someone explain why it removes the Quotation mark from the string and a possible solution?

Answer (score 1):

Use [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals), by inserting an `r` character before the quotes which start the string:

```py
import os

path = os.getcwd()
os.system(r'powershell.exe $env:path += \"' + path + r'\\ProgramFiles\"')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a double quote inside a string delimited by double quotes you need to escape it. Try this -

```
import os

path = os.getcwd()
os.system('powershell.exe $env:path += \"' + path + '\\ProgramFiles\"')
```

Comment: But the string in the question is not delimited by double quotes...